# Pagination not working in DB query Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

`

```
return $all_user = DB::select("SELECT *,
        'STATUS' AS STAT,
        CASE
             WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) <= 1 THEN 'online'
             WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) > 720
               AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) <= 30) THEN 'idle'
             ELSE 'offline'
        END AS user_status
     FROM users")->paginate(20);
```

`

> I'm expecting the result with paginate link. when i put `->paginate(20)` it giving me **Call to a member function paginate() on array** error. please help

Comment: `DB::select()` executes the query immediately and returns an Array; `[]->paginate()` is not valid. Use `DB::table('users')->select('...')->paginate(10)` as the answer below suggests, or use a Model (`User::selectRaw('...')->paginate(10)`)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks  the **Eloquent** Model `User::selectRaw('...')->paginate(10)` is working for me .

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use:

```
return $all_user = DB::table('users')
   ->select(" *,
        'STATUS' AS STAT,
        CASE
             WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) <= 1 THEN 'online'
             WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) > 720
               AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, NOW()) <= 30) THEN 'idle'
             ELSE 'offline'
        END AS user_status
     FROM users")->paginate(20);
```